# Table Valued Function with dynamic select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Creating a user-defined table-valued function which should return `select` `union all` dynamic query.

I have table `tbl_tablesinfo` which contains table names `tbl1`, `tbl2`, `tbl3`, etc. in all around 3000 table names.

I don't want to create view but function which should return `select * from` all tables by doing `union all`.

My attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_alldata()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT 
        @Var = STUFF((SELECT ' SELECT * FROM [' + tbl.TableNames + '] UNION ALL'
                      FROM [TestDB].SYS.TABLES tb 
                      INNER JOIN [TestDB].dbo.[tbl_tablesinfo] tbl ON tb.name = tbl.TableNames
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

    SET @var = LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - 10);

    EXEC @var 

    RETURN
END
```

I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

Reason for doing this is creating view with 3k tables is getting slow and taking around 30 min of time, so I am looking for an alternative by creating function.

Comment: By saying `returns table` without defining the table you are creating an inline table valued function which can only have a `return select` in it. It you want a regular table valued function you need to define the return table. Please consult the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) is clear said, that:

> User-defined functions cannot make use of dynamic SQL or temp tables.
>   Table variables are allowed.

which means that you need to use a stored procedure and this is not bad as you can still insert the data in table if you want:

```
INSERT INTO @Table
EXEC [dbo].[stored_procedured_name]

INSERT INTO #Table
EXEC [dbo].[stored_procedured_name]
```

So, in your case you will have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE udf_alldata
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT 
        @Var = STUFF((SELECT ' SELECT * FROM [' + tbl.TableNames + '] UNION ALL'
                      FROM [TestDB].SYS.TABLES tb 
                      INNER JOIN [TestDB].dbo.[tbl_tablesinfo] tbl ON tb.name = tbl.TableNames
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

    SET @var = LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - 10);

    EXEC sp_executesql @var 

    RETURN
END
```

Note, actually you can execute `dynamic T-SQL in function` but this is special case using SQL CLR. I can show you how to do this, but it will be better to stuck with the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use Dynamic Query in SQL Function...
2. Functions can return only Scalar Values, or Tables...
3. Instead you can use Stored Procedure...

Comment: While this is technically correct it's not much of a quality answer... this would be better off as a comment.